# All cache pages return 404 after crawling with wget

Tags: magento2

I have the weirdest error...

I clear my Magento 2 cache and execute the following wget command to crawl the entire site:

```
wget --spider -o wget.log -e robots=off -r -l 5 -p -S -T3 --header="X-Bypass-Cache: 1" -H --domains=example.com http://example.com --delete-after
```

After I visit with my browser ALL pages, home page, category page, cms pages, product pages return a 404 error.

This does not happen when I clear cache and visit with my browser on the first try instead of using wget.

This is my Nginx config if it has anything to do with it:

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name example.com;
set $MAGE_ROOT /home/httpd/example.com;

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=2G \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /db/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}


location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    #fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=2G \n max_execution_time=600";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}

}
```

Here is the wget log file after trying to crawl and it shows 404 link:

```
$ cat wget.log
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2019-03-22 16:26:52--  http://example.com/
Resolving example.com (example.com)... 111.222.333.444
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|111.222.333.444|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  Server: nginx
  Date: Fri, 22 Mar 2019 15:26:55 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  X-Magento-Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
  X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
  Expires: Thu, 22 Mar 2018 15:26:55 GMT
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!

Found 1 broken link.

http://example.com/
```

How is this technically possible?

How can wget, a client, create 404 cache pages for my entire Magento 2 store?

Comment: do you have any rules in place in .htaccess or somewhere else which blocks spiders/bots and redirects them to a 404 page across the board. I have seen this done on sites to block automated requests (bad bots) from overloading a site.

Comment: Not that I know of. I updated post with my Nginx, maybe there is something there but I can't see it. Even if I use -U flag with a custom browser user agent, I can't crawl anywhere.

Comment: so im guessing that you've edited the logs and files u attached to replace your actual domain with example.com before posting or are you using some local setup ?

Comment: Yes of course, it is hosted on a dev server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a bug in Magento 2.3.0 with HEAD requests.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21299